# Select through xml query

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have

```
declare @xml_var varchar(4000) 
set  @xml_var =  
'<Text  ID = "1">
<Good Number ="Number_0"/>
<Good Number ="Number_1"/>
<Good Number ="Number_2"/>
<Good Number ="Number_3"/>
</Text>'
```

I try to do a script that returns non xml output like this

```
Number_0
Number_1
Number_2
Number_3
```

How can I do it?

I try

```
SELECT 
good.value('@Number', 'nvarchar(50)') as Number
FROM @xml_var.nodes('/Text') col(Text)
```

I do not have access to sql server now, that would be later

OK, I have solution but when I try

```
declare @string varchar(8000)
declare @xml_var xml;  
set  @string =  
'<Text  ID = "1">
<Good Number ="Number_0"/>
<Good Number ="Number_1"/>
<Good Number ="Number_2"/>
<Good Number ="Number_3"/>
</Text>'
SET @xml_var = @string;
SELECT Data.Col.value('@Number', 'nvarchar(100)') AS Number
FROM @xml_var.nodes('/Text/Good') AS Data(Col)
```

there on sql fiddle error appears

Comment: Solution for "I do not have access to sql server now" -> http://sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have to declare your variable/column as `XML` instead of `VARCHAR`.

Then your query should look like that:

```
SELECT T.N.value('@Number', 'nvarchar(100)') AS Number
FROM @xml_var.nodes('/Text/Good') AS T(N)
```

Working [**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/23151). You can use SQL Fiddle to test queries like that one when you don't have access to your database.

Comment: Thanks. I used that but I declare variable in left column

Comment: XML variable is logical. Big thanks but for correction. But I not create that task. Is there soultion for varchar variable? Or that totaly wrong?

Comment: You can always create XML from `varchar`: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/converting-string-data-to-xml-and-xml-to-string-data/

Comment: Delete `;` at the end of added lines.

Comment: OK, now I delete it everywhere. That works. That question is solved.